# discord.py edited message logging issue

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I've making some code that will allow me to log edited messages to a certain channel. Here is the code:

```
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before, message.author), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
    embed.add_field(name= message_before.content ,value="This is the message before the edit:", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name= message_after.content ,value="This is the message after the edit", inline=True)
    channel=bot.get_channel(747057143630528563)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the error message:

Ignoring exception in on_message_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\jackt\Desktop\bot.py", line 92, in on_message_edit
embed=discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before, message.author), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

What part of the code do I need to change, and what do I need to change about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before, message.author), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
```

should actually be

```
discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before.author.name), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
```

The reason you got the `message is not defined` error before is because you added a comma here: `message_before, message.author`. This makes python think that they're two different statements, making it try to access the message variable (which does not exist).

Instead, you should access the message_before object. I added `.name` to retrieve the name as just using `.author` would just add a User object. If you want to just mention the user, then you can replace `.name` with `.mention`.

Edit: Also add `@bot.event` at the top of the function so it gets called on a message edit. The code should look like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before.author.name), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
    embed.add_field(name= message_before.content ,value="This is the message before the edit:", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name= message_after.content ,value="This is the message after the edit", inline=True)
    channel=bot.get_channel(747057143630528563)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: That stopped the error from appearing, but now no message gets sent to my channel when a message is edited, but also no error appears. Basically, nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using py3.6 or higher? If so, you could try replacing title with `f"{message_before.author.name} edited a message"`to see if that makes any difference. Also you could try running `print(channel)` after defining it to see if it returns None or not @JackThorn

Comment: I tried adding the f" thing, but it did nothing. I also added print(channel) to the last line of the script, but nothing was sent. I also tried print("Edited"), but the word edited wasn't sent, so perhaps the on_message_edit isn't being triggered properly? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `@client.event` above `async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):`? Unless if you already have it there

Comment: I forgot to add @bot.event lol. No wonder nothing happened. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Since this solved your question, could you mark my answer as the one that solved it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your using `message.author` in the first line of you definition:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before, message.author), description="", color=0xFFFF00)
```

However `message` was never declared, hence the "not defined" error your getting

One fix for this could be using:
`message_before.author.name`

Comment: Thanks, that stopped the error from appearing, but now no message gets sent to my channel when a message is edited, but also no error appears. Basically, nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @JackThorn i dont know, it couldnt be the channel id since it sounds like it was working before, i cant help you there